# putchar('0'+ num) function in C

Tags: c

Consider the following “mystery” function:

```
void pb(int n)
{
  if (n != 0) 
  {
    pb(n / 2);
    putchar('0' + n % 2);
  }
}
```

If I input a number to this function, what does the function do?

Also, what does the `putchar('0' + n % 2)` do in this function?

Comment: Did you try running it?

Comment: print number as binary.

Comment: What does your beginner's C text book tell you about operators and data types?

Answer (score 2):

As [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) said, the function `pb()` accepts an integer `n` as parameter and prints its binary equivalent.

The `putchar('0' + n % 2)` is for printing the binary.

`'0'` will give the encoded value for zero (if it's ASCII the value is 48). The value of `'0'` added with `1` or `0` will give the encoded value of 1 or 0 respectively.

Let's consider an example where `n` is `10`.

Binary of `10` is `1010`.

```
pb(10);                 ----> putchar('0' + 10%2);       ----> 0
    pb(5)               ----> putchar('0' + 5%2);        ----> 1
        pb(2)           ----> putchar('0' + 2%2);        ----> 0
            pb(1)       ----> putchar('0' + 1%2);        ----> 1
                pb(0)
```

`pb()` is being called recursively till its argument is `0` and value of a bit is printed corresponding to each recursion.

In this way, for `10`, `1010` is printed out.

Comment: Try `pb(-123)`.

Answer (score -5):

regarding:

```
putchar('0' + n % 2);
```

the `n%2` will result in 0 or 1.

However, the '+' operator has higher precedence than the '%' operator so this line will not do what is expected.

the '0' is a character 0 and actually contains '0x30'  So the line is expected to output a 0 or a 1 to the display.

To make it work correctly, suggest using parens as in:

```
putchar( '0' + (n % 2) );
```

regarding *what does the function do*

I have added comments to the code

```
void pb(int n)
{
    if (n != 0)      // check if need to perform another recursion
    {
        pb(n / 2);   // recursive call to 'pb()' 
                     // passing the 'n' parameter divided by 2.
                     // this in an integer divide, 
                     // so when the parameter is less than 2 
                     // the result will be 0
        putchar('0' + n % 2);
                     // this line will be executed 
                     // after all the following recursive calls have exited
                     // the result is:
                     // output the original 'n' value as a binary number,
                     // with the most significant bit displayed first
    }
}
```

Note:  this recursive function will 'eat' a lot of the stack space.          Much better to use a simple loop

Comment: `%` has the same precedence of `/` and `*`, which is higher than binary `+`, exactly as in regular math (BO[DM][AS] or however they call it). Maybe you got confused by the unary `+` operator?

Comment: Who told you the add operator has a higher precedence than modulus operator??? See [C Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) (Class 3 `*/%` and Class 4 `+-`) before posting an answer please.

Comment: I see, I was looking at the urinary '+' and not at the mathematical '+'

Comment: `putchar('0' + n % 2);` will print `'0'`, `'1'` or `'0' - 1`.

Comment: the function `putchar()` only outputs a single character, I.E. the expression with the parens is evaluated until a single character remains, then that single character is output to `stdout`.   It will never output '0' -1